# Unsupported protocol ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-core, google-chrome, ssl

I have a problem with Google Chrome. I've just created ASP.NET Core project (Visual Studio 2019) and when I launched it I noticed this problem:

> ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
> The site localhost uses unsupported protocol

I haven't changed anything in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try cleaning up the old self-signed certificate and re-issue a new one

```
dotnet dev-certs https –-clean
dotnet dev-certs https –-trust
```

Also to bypass this, you may enable insecure localhost trust in chrome, not recommended though but would do the job for you

```
chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost
```